# time_ago_in_words and localize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, internationalization

Is it possible to use `time_ago_in_words` with `i18n.locale`?

how?

thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are using Rails > 2.2, the helper is already locale-aware.

Just download the right localization file from the [locale repository](http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale) and store it into your `/config/locales` path. Then set your locale preferences.

Answer (score 8):

Avoid doing it on the server and try it on the client instead by using the [jQuery timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/).  Timeago has support for i18n.

This turns this:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

Into this:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="July 17, 2008">about a year ago</abbr>
```

And [supports language overrides](http://gist.github.com/6251).

Comment: Although awkward at first sight, doing this on client side has one very clear advantage: time info on your page never gets noncurrent (in case that you save page for offline access, for example). Search engines also shouldn't be interested in "humanized" version of timestamps.